# Multi-tenant site for small buiness?

Tags: database

I don't know if that is the correct term for what I'm talking about but basically I'm thinking about building a single website for small businesses that uses databases to display different information (eg. company name, about me / other text) depending on which domain you go to.

For example,  ABC.com shows an ABC logo in the header and 123.com shows a 123 logo.

Can this be done with php or is this handled with some other language?

Oh and just want to know if this seems like overkill for small business brochure sites?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, such applications are indeed called Multi-Tenant, and PHP will meet your needs. However, if you want to bootstrap your development process of a multi-tenant web app or SaaS in PHP, you might want to try [Innomatic](http://www.innomatic.io/)